# 2 problem with minspantree.m in Matlab 2018a

Tags: matlab, function, graph

2  problem with minspantree.m in Matlab 2018a

Hi dear all; I want to find a  min-span-tree of a matrix. I figured that MATLAB's own minspantree.m may be the most  efficient algorithm. So i use
open minspantree.m

And here comes Question:

1.The code in minspantree.m used G.EdgeProperties.Weight and G.Underlying. G is a graph object. But when I use G.EdgeProperties.Weight or G.Underlying in Command window, both returns error: Error using graph/subsref (line 15)  No public property 'EdgeProperties' for class 'graph'. Why?

2.minspantree.m line 62：

```
[pred, edgeind] = primMinSpanningTree(G.Underlying, w, rootNode, restart);
```

Is primMinSpanningTree a function? But I can not find any: function [ ] = primMinSpanningTree() in minspantree.m,  neither can I find primMinSpanningTree.m file in my whole disk. So what is primMinSpanningTree? What is its code? How can I find it and open it?
Thanks  all very much.

Comment: So why do you not just create a graph and call `minspantree` on it? Do you not have 2018a, or is there something else holding you back?

Comment: 1.I want to learn its algorithm.
2.I want to change something, more customized.

Comment: The pseudocode for Prim's algorithm is available in most algorithms textbooks (at least the ones I've seen) and has many descriptions and implementations online. It is also one of the easier algorithms to implement using only an adjacency matrix and then improve by adding more complex data structures. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm) has a good discussion of the implementation. If you want to learn the algorithm, I suggest you try implementing it yourself. We'll be here to help if you run into problems.

Answer (score 1):

1. Both `EdgeProperties` and `Underlying` are private properties of the graph class. They can only be accessed from within the class. Take a look at `Graph.m`. `minspantree` is a class method, so it has access.
2. `primMinSpanningTree` is a built-in method from `matlab.internal.graph.MLGraph`. You can see that with `which primMinSpanningTree`. So I believe the code might not be accessible.

Comment: Thank you so much. I kind of figure this out myself. It is really disturbing that Matlab don't share its  built-in method like primMinSpanningTree. Maybe they do this is for the purpose of copyright protection. However, it will cause users a big trouble when they want to change something or learn something.

Comment: So suprising that SO does not have friends-system. I wish I could add u as friend.